# Which is better to use useMemo or useCallback when the function comes as a dependency on useMemo dependency array

Tags: reactjs

I have a piece of code wrapped in useMemo that uses a function as a dependency that returns some data, is it worth using useMemo in this case since we return data, or is it better to useCallback

Example:

```
 // useMemo vs useCallback ?
 const getConfigs = useCallback((configs)=> {
   return configs.filter(...some filtering logic)
 }, [])

const getConfigs = useMemo(()=> {
   return configs.filter(...some filtering logic)
 }, [props.configs])

 const someMemoData = useMemo(()=>{
   return {
     names: props.names,
     configs: getConfigs(props.configs) or getConfigs in case useMemo
  }
 }, [props.names, getConfigs, props.configs])
```

Comment: "useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps)" https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return data use useMemo

If you return function use useCallback

They both accept same parameters. Their first argument is a callback. The only difference is that:

```
useMemo(cb) returns cb()
useCallback(cb) returns cb
```

`useCallback(() => {})` is same as `useMemo(() => () => {})`

Your getConfigs returns a function, so better use useCallback for it. While someMemoData returns object, use useMemo

Comment: But getConfigs return object calculations , no?

Comment: It returns some calculations. But no need to use useMemo(() => () => {}), as you can use useCallback(() => {})

Comment: Yes, probably it's better use useMemo and remove function, thanks

Comment: your useCallback version is not correct. It should be useCallback((configs) => ...). It always depends in the situation which one is better. If you care only on someMemoData, I would put them in single useMemo together with getConfigs. If you want to memoize the value, use useMemo. If you want to keep the function reference, use useCallback.